# Why are ticket offenders called "portoghesi"?

Tags: idioms

In a number of press articles, people who abuse the public transport service by not buying a ticket are normally called "portoghesi" (Portugueses).

What is the origin of that expression? Isn't it offensive against the inhabitants of Portugal who have their own paid public transport service?
Or is it that Portugal offers free transport to everyone?

Examples from news:

- Maggiori controlli per stanare i portoghesi del biglietto
- Tentava di fare il *portoghese*
- L'annoso problema dei *portoghesi*

Comment: Now that you have seen the reason for this idiom, it will be clear to you that it is not “offensive against the inhabitants of Portugal”, but rather against Italians who pretended to be Portuguese, since Portuguese people were the ones actually entitled to free theatre or whatever.

Comment: ticket offenders are always an offensive topic....

Comment: If you know how to read Portuguese, [this article](https://www.natgeo.pt/historia/2021/01/non-fare-il-portoghese-conheca-a-origem-da-expressao-italiana) may be useful.

Comment: I can't, but my browser can!

Answer (score 9):

[The origin](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fare_il_portoghese) is not certain and there are two main historical hypothesis which have to do with episodes where Portuguese authorities are involved with the papacy.

> - Un'ipotesi è che l'espressione sia relativa ad un fatto storico avvenuto a Roma nel XVIII secolo, quando l'ambasciatore del Portogallo presso lo Stato Pontificio invitò i portoghesi residenti a Roma ad assistere gratuitamente a uno spettacolo teatrale presso il Teatro Argentina; non vi era bisogno di invito formale, in quanto bastava dichiarare la propria nazionalità.
> - Altra ipotesi è che il re del Portogallo ottenne dal Papa l'esenzione dal dazio per entrare a Roma per i portoghesi, a seguito della donazione dell'oro servito alla decorazione del cassettonato di Santa Maria Maggiore. Molti romani, tuttavia, cercarono di approfittare dell'opportunità spacciandosi per portoghesi, da cui l'avvertimento non fare il portoghese per diffidare chicchessia dal mettere in atto trucchi o raggiri per poter usufruire di un servizio senza averne titolo.

(Wikipedia)